# Satisfy this JPQL requirement

Tags: jpa, jpql, spring-data-jpa

Requirement: The content of one string is present in the other. This tests on whole words only, but multi-word queries are allowed. For example, a query with `givenName:Jane` will match users with `givenName` values of "Jane" and "Jane Ann", but not "Janet". A multi-word query for `givenName:Mary Ann` would match values of "Mary Ann Evans" and "Sarah Mary Ann" but not "Ann Mary".

This is what I have so far.
I have a `SiteRepository` that extends the `JpaRepository` interface and it consists of the following method.

```
@Query("SELECT s from Site s WHERE s.name LIKE :givenName")
public List<Site> findByName(@Param("givenName") String givenName);
```

Now, the user is suppose to pass in a String value to the method below (for example ":Jane" or ":Mary Ann").

```
public List<Site> findByName(String givenName) //Where Site is an entity with a name field.
```

In the above method, I essentially check the first character of the parameter `giveName` to see if it is ":" and if it is, I substring `givenName` to cut out the colon and concatenate the following characters.

```
return siteRepository.findByName("%" + givenName.substring(1, givenName.length()) + "%"  
                + " AND NOT LIKE _" + givenName.substring(1, givenName.length()) + "_");
```

So if I called, `findByName(":Jane")`
I should get the following JPQL query: `SELECT s from Site s WHERE s.name LIKE %Jane% AND NOT LIKE _Jane_`

This however does not work.  Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write a query which checks whether all the words are present and the first index of a word is before the last index of the next word.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  Do you mind showing me how to write a jpql query like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  This seems to work for the cases I tested so far.

" SELECT s FROM Site s WHERE s.name NOT LIKE 'Jane_' AND s.name NOT LIKE '_Jane' AND s.name NOT LIKE '*Jane*' AND s.name LIKE '%Jane%' "

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in jpql, so I will write here only my assumptions which are not necessarily correct, but I try to help the op anyways.

If my answer is wrong, then please, leave a comment at the answer to let me know about it.

I think this answer does not deserve to be down-voted, as I have made clear that my answer is not necessarily correct and I will remove it if it is incorrect.

This was my idea described as a comment to the question without knowing the technical details:

> You should write a query which checks whether all the words are
>   present and the first index of a word is before the last index of the
>   next word.

```
LOCATE(searchString, candidateString [, startIndex])
```

searches for the position of `searchString` in `candidateString` starting from `startIndex`, indexes being started from 1. The idea is to write a query which checks whether the locate returns other than 0 having a value of `startIndex` dependent of the `startIndex` of the previous string. ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html)) If all your strings match the criteria, then the record should be included into the results.